# Information Conflicts About Operator Precedence

Tags: c, expression, operator-precedence, associativity

I've recently been reading Pointers on C book of Kenneth A. Reek. The book has a really nice table of C operators and their precedence levels. However, when I checked other resources to make sure information provided in the book is correct and up-to-date, I've seen there are varying information around. I'll provide precise examples to show what I exactly mean.

The book provides a table where the function call operator `()` has the highest precedence. Postfix increment and decrement operators are coming after. I've checked other resources to validate the information. I've checked this [resource](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-operator-precedence-and-associativity/) and this [resource](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) and this [resource](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html). The precedence information provided in these resources match with what is explained in Pointer on C book. Problem starts with [precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) in cppreference because it has different precedence rules than other resources.

So am I missing something?

Comment: care to mention what is the mismatch?

Comment: Given that `()` is a postfix operator, its precedence with regard to postfix `++` and `--` is entirely irrelevant. The order of operators determines which is applied first.

Comment: Postfix increment and decrement operators comes **before** function call operator in cppreference

Comment: The boxes at cppreference indicate sets of operators with equal priority.

Comment: This might help you : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/

Answer (score 6):

As [already mentioned in the linked resource](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

> **Operators that are in the same cell (there may be several rows of operators listed in a cell) are evaluated with the same precedence, in the given direction.** For example, the expression `a=b=c` is parsed as `a=(b=c)`, and not as `(a=b)=c` because of right-to-left associativity.

So, the written order of operators (with same precedence) ***in any article*** does not matter much, the associativity (as present in the actual statement to be evaluated) is important.